# Dynamic Django form fields based on ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to create a form field for each question in a given question group. I'm very new to python/django so this may be a bad approach, high level suggestions welcome. Here is what I have:

models.py:

```
class QuestionGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    modified = models.DateTimeField()

class Question(models.Model):
    question_content = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    question_group = models.ForeignKey(QuestionGroup)
```

views.py:

```
def give_feedback(request, group_id):
    question_list = Question.objects.filter(question_group = group_id)
    form = ResponseForm(question_list)
```

forms.py:

```
class ResponseForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for q in args:
            q.question_content = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

I get "'ResponseForm' object has no attribute '_errors'". Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's the problem here, but you should probably call the parent Form initialization method in your overridden __init__:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ResponseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    for q in args:
        q.question_content = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

Comment: That was part of my issue, thanks! The other problem was I needed to use             self.fields[q.question_content] = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)